# Why alias_method is an instance method?

Tags: ruby

Below is the typical usage of alias_method,

```
class A
def say
    puts 'say'      
end

alias_method :talk, :say
end
```

alias_method is a private **instance** method defined in Module class, but in above code, it's more like a **class** method instead of an **instance** method, why does the above code work?

Comment: You have been using stackoverflow for two months, asked three questions, and have not accepted any answers. If you are satisfied with none of the answers so far, that is alright, but if any of the answer are correct, please accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a class method of `A` as you correctly notice, and is at the same time an instance method of `Module` class, of which the `Class` class is a subclass. Class methods are not exclusive to instance methods. All class methods are instance methods of the `Class` class unless they are methods on a singleton class.

In the above example, `alias_method` is defined on `Module` class. So, `A`, which is an instance of `Module` can be the receiver of a method call to `alias_method`. But since this method is private, the receiver needs to implicit.

Comment: In Ruby, every class is an instance of Class class, in my example, class A is an instance of Class, and because Module is the base class of Class, then A is an instance of Module, is that true? If that is true, I can understand that why Module's private instance method becomes the class method of A.

One more question: since Object is the base class of Module, so all of the Object's instance methods will become the class methods of class A, right?

Comment: That is exactly the case.